# Making new row of bootstrap float left while breaks onto new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

[image]

```html
<style>
.xx{
 min-height: 40px;
 margin-top:15px;
 background: white;
}
.yy{
 min-height: 100px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 background: white;
}
.zz{
 min-height: 95px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 background: white;
}
.pp{
 min-height: 120px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 background: white;

}
</style>
<div style="background:grey; min-height:600px;">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="text1 xx">This is text 1</div>
<div class="text3 xx">This is text 3</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="text2 xx">This is text 2</div>
<div class="text4 xx">This is text 4</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="text6 zz">This is text 6</div>
<div class="text7 pp">This is text 7</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="text5 yy">This is text 5</div>

</div>





</div>
</div>
```

Problem : The div in the third column, containing `this is text 6`  can be of variable height.

Requirement : `5` should be undisturbed by the height of 3rd column and should be aligned just below `3` and `4` . Further, on resizing the window to mobile size, stacking should be in order : 1,3,2,4,6

SO far I've tried :
If we move `this is text 7` div along with `this is text 5` then also it will not solve the problem , as `this is text 6` is of variable height. `6` & `7` have to be in same column, while making `5` aligned somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Since 5 and 7 should be aligned, I created a new row for these columns. It is allowed to have rows inside columns, thats why i created 2 rows, 1 containing the upper 5 columns and the other row containing text-7 and text-5. This way text5 and 7 are aligned and will be below the first row based on the height of text6.

```
<div style="background:grey; min-height:600px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="text1 xx">This is text 1</div>
          <div class="text3 xx">This is text 3</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="text2 xx">This is text 2</div>
          <div class="text4 xx">This is text 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="text6 zz">This is text 6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="text5 yy">This is text 5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="text7 pp">This is text 7</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try increasing the height of `6` , I've mentioned it is of variable height. 
U'll notice the whole div `5` will also shift down

Comment: Created a bootply for your case, I created a sidebar (col4) which contains 6 and 7, and created a main (col8) which contains 1,2,3,4,5. See http://www.bootply.com/SGeY3ZYnBY

Comment: hmm.. even I was thinking the same. Problem with this structure is that we want 1,3,2,4,6,5,7 order when viewed in mobile view, which I've mentioned in the question...

Comment: Ah, strange idea. But it is possible. By duplicating the content and use `hidden-md` and `hidden-xs` classes for hiding/showing the right column on the right device